# Networkx: Differences between pagerank, pagerank_numpy, and pagerank_scipy?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, networkx, pagerank

Does anyone know about the differences in accuracy between the three different pagerank functions in Networkx?

I have a graph of 1000 nodes and 139732 edges, and the "plain" `pagerank` function didn't seem to work at all -- all but two of the nodes had the same PG, so I'm assuming this function doesn't work quite as well for large graphs?

`pagerank_numpy`'s values also seemed to be a little bit more spread out than `pagerank_scipy`'s values. The documentation for this function says that "This will be the fastest and most accurate for small graphs." What is meant by "small" graphs?

Also, why doesn't pagerank_numpy allow for `max_iter` and `tol` arguments?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Each of the three functions uses a different approach to solving the same problem:

`networkx.pagerank()` is a pure-Python implementation of the power-method to compute the largest eigenvalue/eigenvector or the Google matrix.  It has two parameters that control the accuracy - `tol` and `max_iter`.

`networkx.pagerank_scipy()` is a SciPy sparse-matrix implementation of the power-method.  It has the same two accuracy parameters.

`networkx.pagerank_numpy()` is a NumPy (full) matrix implementation that calls the `numpy.linalg.eig()` function to compute the largest eigenvalue and eigenvector.  That function is an interface to the LAPACK dgeev function which is uses a matrix decomposition (direct) method with no tunable parameters.

All three should produce the same answer (within numerical roundoff) for well-behaved graphs if the `tol` parameter is small enough and the `max_iter` parameter is large enough.  Which one is faster depends on the size of your graph and how well the power method works on your graph.

```
In [12]: import networkx as nx

In [13]: G=nx.gnp_random_graph(1000,0.01,directed=True)

In [14]: %timeit nx.pagerank(G,tol=1e-10)
10 loops, best of 3: 157 ms per loop

In [15]: %timeit nx.pagerank_scipy(G,tol=1e-10)
100 loops, best of 3: 14 ms per loop

In [16]: %timeit nx.pagerank(G)
10 loops, best of 3: 137 ms per loop
```

Comment: Awesome explanation, thanks! By the way, how does pagerank_numpy know when to stop without those tunable parameters?

Comment: The algorithm that computes the eigenvalues in pagerank_numpy() (LAPACK's dgeev) does a fixed number of operations that depends only on the matrix size.  I think it should be roughly n^3 where n is the number of nodes.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/713878/how-expensive-is-it-to-compute-the-eigenvalues-of-a-matrix for a longer discussion of this in the context of PageRank.

Comment: By the way, what do you mean by "well-behaved graphs"? Graphs that are connected and have no dead ends? Because I wonder if the disprecancies in the results I observe could be due to that...